# easelJS IE9 bitmap not loading

Tags: html5-canvas, easeljs

I'm having trouble using easelJS to render Bitmap in IE9.  Every other browser renders the image fine, but IE9 canvas is blank.  I even tried preload the image in a hidden div and it still doesn't work.  here's my code, help please!

```
function init(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
        var ship= new createjs.Bitmap(ship.png);
        stage.addChild(ship);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call stage.update() after adding the child.  Also, you'll need to wait until the image is fully loaded.  Check out [PreloadJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS), by the makers of EaselJS to help you handle this.

Comment: Thanks.  Dugged up PreloadJS and it helped a lot.